# How to read several different commands in one method?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to read many different commands in one method passing `int year` as a parameter for the method. The method should read 3 different commands, for example for year 2017, 2018 and 2019.

What I have done so far is the following

```cs
public int GetSumYear(int year)
{
    int sum = 0;
    string CS = "+++++"

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select COUNT (ÜbertragenAm) from BranchSale_all where ÜbertragenAm between '2017-01-01' and '2018-01-01'", connection);

        // here i want to read the same command for 2018 and 2019

        sum = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: [between](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) is something you can better avoid

Comment: What does "Read a command" mean? How about you just query once like `select YEAR(ÜbertragenAm) as  ÜbertragenAm, COUNT (ÜbertragenAm) as  ÜbertragenAmCount from BranchSale_all where ÜbertragenAm between '2017-01-01' and '2020-01-01' GROUP BY YEAR(ÜbertragenAm) ` and then get what you need from the result set returned?

Comment: What is your goal? Do you need the singular sum from all 3 years, do you want a sum per year? Why are you trying to do it all in one go? Are you actually not using any type of parameter in your code or is this just an oversimplified example?

Comment: What have you tried?  We cannot answer the question until you tell us what you tried and how it fails.

Comment: @Flater. my goal to get the sum of every year 2017,2018 and 2019 and i want all that just in one method .and i havent used parameter in my code . that was the question if i should do it or not

Comment: @JNevill. it works very well . thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off doing some sort of aggregation at the DB level than issuing separate queries

```
select 
     YEAR(ÜbertragenAm) year,
     COUNT(*) count
from BranchSale_all 
where YEAR(ÜbertragenAm) IN (2017,2018,2019)
group by YEAR(ÜbertragenAm)
```